# Can we use a single layer perceptron on multiclass classification probleme?

Tags: neural-network, multiclass-classification, perceptron, slp

1. Can we use a single layer perceptron on multiclass classification problem?
2. How can we show that those classes are non-linearly separable if we had 30 features ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes ye can use single layer perceptron (slp) for multi-class classification. We can employ one-vs-all or one-vs-one strategy for this. SLP are like logistic classifiers which are linearly separable so if the dataset is not linearly separable then you might wanna consider using Multi-layer perceptron.
2. I am not sure to what you are asking, but as to my understanding, if we can separate 2 classes by a straight line, they are linearly separable. This means that if in your dataset you can draw straight lines which separates examples from each other, then the problem is linearly separable. It is not usually the case though.

I really liked this [blog](https://jtsulliv.github.io/perceptron/). You might wanna check it out.